# Social network visualization tools for PHP/JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, python, visualization, social-networking

I'm looking for a tool that will allow me to display visualizations of social networks dynamically online.  There are a lot of great visualization examples out there already:

http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/the_best_tools_for_visualization.php

http://socialmediatrader.com/10-amazing-visualizations-of-social-networks/

I know lots of sites have specific widgets (such as last.fm), but what I want is a flexible tool that I can integrate with my own database of people and organizations.  At the most basic level, I need something that will show lines/arcs/edges between people and/or organizations, and include the ability to manipulate width, color, length, etc, or lines.

I'm aware of some tools such as XML/SWF Charts http://www.maani.us/xml_charts/index.php, but not sure that tool includes the ability to visualize social networks.

I'm most proficient in PHP/JavaScript/CSS, but would also appreciate hearing any suggestions for Python.

Answer (score 3):

I really really recommend you to give [Gephi](http://gephi.org/) a try (along with a suitable browser-based GEXF viewer).

Gephi is an open source graph visualization and manipulation software written in Java. It runs on Windows, Linux and Mac OS X. Gephi is open-source and free.

- Gephi's [plugin architecture](http://gephi.org/plugins/) allows you to write custom plugins. In your case you might wish to write a custom plugin to read data from your database to Gephi.
- But oh wait -- if your data is already in a database (MySQL, SQL Server, PostgreSQL) you could even use Gephi's built-in database importer!
- Gephi definitely gives you the basic visualisations you expect from an SNA tool (lines/arcs/edges between objects and ability to manipulate width, color, length, etc. of both lines and nodes).
- Again, if you need some extra visualisation tools, you can write your own visualisation plugin
- Data from Gephi can be exported to CSV, GDF, GEXF and Graphml as well as to SVG and PDF.

For web intergration, you can export data from Gephi in GEXF format and visualise it in a webpage with something like [gexf-js](https://github.com/raphv/gexf-js) (GEXF graph visualiser with zoom and pan and hyperlinking support). Alternative libraries with GEXF support include [sigmajs](http://sigmajs.org/) and [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/) for Python.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  It looks like a really comprehensive solution and I'll dig into a little bit.

Comment: The OP asked for something dynamic, Gephi is great for visualisations locally but for a dynamic web-based experience it seems better to go with @Tomas A's answer.

Comment: @sijpkes: You are right. Updated answer to provide link to JavaScript-based GEXF viewer (the Flash one was dead anyways).

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend Networkx + protovis/d3 for python.
Processing.js is quite flexible to create a network viz from scratch (try ben fry´s Data visualization).

Answer (score 1):

you could give GraphViz a try: http://www.graphviz.org

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation.  I'm not that familiar with it, but it likes it doesn't have great usability.

Comment: Actually you can take a look at this of what is possible using GraphViz: http://www2.research.att.com/areas/visualization/projects_software/img/ATT_Labs_InternetMap_0730_10.pdf

Comment: Those are some really amazing visualizations.  I'll dig a little deeper.

Answer (score 0):

There's a commercially licensed JavaScript toolkit that does exactly this - called [KeyLines](http://key-lines.com) - designed for integrating with your own data.

(Disclaimer - I'm a developer of it!)