# How to create svg of user's friends

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cakephp, svg

I am trying to create a visualization of which employees are friends with each other. I am trying to create a visualization out of our internal social network. Something like Nexus facebook app did back in 2007.

I think nexus used python and javascript to achieve this. Me a php & javascript noob. I appreciate if any anybody can share libraries that can used to achieve this.

I appreciate all your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Social network visualization tools for PHP/JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937833/social-network-visualization-tools-for-php-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quickest solution would be to use [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) - you'll need shell access though